# An applescript stopped working after upgrade from snow leopard to lion

Tags: applescript

This script worked every time with Snow Leopard.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd web_sites/project" in front window   # this line highlighted on error
    do script "mate ." in front window
    do script "rvm 1.8.7" in front window
    do script "script/server" in front window
    delay 4
    do shell script "open -a Firefox http://localhost:3000"
end tell
```

With Lion I keep getting this error:

```
error "Terminal got an error: Can’t get window 1." number -1728 from window 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to remove "in front window" part of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is not the code but the speed at which the operating system is functioning. As i mentioned before, the code executed just fine in Snow Leopard. To compensate, after the upgrade to Lion, if i add another delay to give Terminal time to finish activating, and increase the delay before opening Firefox, everything works. My laptop is a MacBook Pro with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 processor.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 1
    do script "cd web_sites/project" in front window   # this line highlighted on error
    do script "mate ." in front window
    do script "rvm 1.8.7" in front window
    do script "script/server" in front window
    delay 5
    do shell script "open -a Firefox http://localhost:3000"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Lion. I can execute the following with no errors. I do not get an error in Applescript in any of the following situations 1) the application is not running, 2) the app is running and a window is open, and 3) the app is running and the directory path is not valid. In case 3 the Terminal shows an error but applescript does not.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd Development/Images" in front window -- this line highlighted on error
    do script "ls -al" in front window
end tell
```

So your problem is something not related to this actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get a script to run once, simply retrying may help. Execution speed is also a function of other demands on the system.